# button in frames in python

Tags: python, button, tkinter, frames

[image]
Design of my game is something like this
I need to develop Strategic tic tac toe(where in each block of tic tac toe we will find a tic tac toe)....so here i created 9 frames and each frame has 9 buttons...
but when i click the button in any frame changes appear only in one frame ie; in (0,2) i know because its the last frame which is to be called..so i need help to rectify the problem...i tried but i did not get it thanks in advance
Here's my code

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Simple Design")
root.geometry("300x300")


class Design:
    count = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.duplicates = {}
        self.block = {}
        self.button = {}
        for i in range(3):
            for j in range(3):
                self.duplicates[i, j] = "."
        self.frame()

    def frame(self):
        for i, j in self.duplicates:
            self.block[i, j] = Frame(root, background="blue")
            self.block[i, j].grid(row=i, column=j, ipadx=5, ipady=2)
            self.button_create(self.block[i, j])

    def button_create(self, frame):
        for i, j in self.duplicates:
            handler = lambda a=i, b=j: self.update(a, b)
            self.button[i, j] = Button(frame, command=handler, text=".", height=3, width=5)
            self.button[i, j].grid(row=i, column=j)

    def update(self, i, j):

        if (Design.count % 2 == 0):
            self.button[i, j]["text"] = "X"
            Design.count += 1
        else:
            self.button[i, j]["text"] = "O"
            Design.count += 1
        self.button[i, j]["state"] = "disabled"
        print (i, j)


d = Design()  # out of class
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your button handler: how can each button know its coordinates?

Just replace:

```
handler = lambda a=i, b=j: self.update(a, b)
```

By:

```
handler = lambda: self.update(i, j)
```

There is also a bug in `frame` method:
You iterate `duplicates` and then call `button_create` which again iterates `duplicates`. So buttons are redefined in the inner loop.

You can change `button_create` like this:

```
def button_create(self, frame, i, j):
    handler = lambda: self.update(i, j)
    self.button[i, j] = Button(frame, command=handler, text=".", height=3, width=5)
    self.button[i, j].grid(row=i, column=j)
```

And then adapt the call in `frame` as follow:

```
def frame(self):
    for i, j in self.duplicates:
        self.block[i, j] = Frame(root, background="blue")
        self.block[i, j].grid(row=i, column=j, ipadx=5, ipady=2)
        self.button_create(self.block[i, j], i, j)
```

Also note that you ought to inherit `object` class to use new-style classes:

```
class Design(object):
    ...
```

Instead of a `if ... else`, you can use a mapping to calculate the symbol "X" or "O" in `update`:

```
def update(self, i, j):
    symbol = {0: "X", 1: "O"}[Design.count % 2]
    self.button[i, j]["text"] = symbol
    Design.count += 1
    self.button[i, j]["state"] = "disabled"
    print (i, j)
```

Or simply:

```
symbol = "XO"[Design.count % 2]
```

Comment: No its not that.... when i replace handler now it changes text only in frame(0,2) in that button(0,2)..other buttons remain same the don't change any text when i click on them.

Comment: I have kept an image of my design..what u said does not do something like that it just keeps an frame on frame..but i don't need that..my problem is when i click any button text changes only on top right frame.

Comment: OK, You have a **main frame** with 9 **boards**, which contains a 3×3 matrix of **buttons** (a total of 81 buttons). Is it right? You should have a class for the **main frame** and a class for the **board frames** (instanciated 9 times). It will be easier to implement.

Comment: Yeah...what i did was create 9 frames ,each frame contains 3*3 board..but when i click the button on any frame it does not change the text of that button...rather it changes text of button in frame of (0,2)